# Database: wrong user or password; user: "SA" error in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, h2

I want to connect to **H2** data base by Intellij, but I faced following error:

```
database: wrong user or password; user: "SA" error in Intellij
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out the error is because of setting user `sa` but password is empty that should be used `""` for empty password that in Intellij right click and set empty.

[image]